# how to calculate proportion of pixles beteen raster layers which have different resolution in qgis

Tags: qgis

I'm new to qgis. I'm bit struggling using it.
I have two raster layers which have different resolution.
Each map contains color indexs of enviroments. It's land cover map.

raster image 1 : resolution 5 x 5 of land cover map
raster image 2 : resolution 100 x 100 of land cover map

I want to calculate the ratio of each index between two images. I want to know how many subdivided indexes(image 1) occupy within index pixels of a larger classification(image 2). For example, on a large resolutioin map, when a pixel appears as a red dot it means a transportation area. However, image 1 contains more detail. image 2 can be subdivided  into airports, ports, railways, and roads.

Is there a way to statistics the number of each detailed index contained within the large pixel resolution data?

[overlay image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdyTj.png)

qgis raster image analysis